# How to make 3D particles in Monogame?

Tags: xna, 3d, monogame, particles

I have made a 2D game and right now I am converting it to a 3D game. All fine so far, only for the particles I had used the particles library from [monogame extended](https://www.monogameextended.net/docs/features/particles/particles/) but this library only supports 2D particles based on sprites.

I was unable to find other ones besides the ones in other engines like Unity / Godot / Unreal /

How can I make 3D particles for my game?

Comment: Particle systems are mostly screen oriented 2D sprites(even in 3D engines). The only difference is scaling by depth in 3D.

Comment: What do you mean by 3D particles, exactly? Moving in 3D space? Each particle having a volume? (why?) As mentioned elsewhere, particle systems overwhelmingly use sprites, even in 3D (Unity's page says `A particle system simulates and renders many small images or Meshes`). Do your particles need to have a volume? (If so, explaining why might help us find alternatives)

Comment: @MonoGameGuru I just want to create effects like smoke or explosions. When I look at the effect from a different angle then it should look different, doesn't it? Can I achieve this with 2D particles?

Comment: @Basic what exactly do you mean with volume? having a scaling or having a mesh or something like that? What I need to the smoke effect are particles that get larger and more translucent over time which is possible, but it is not 3D

Comment: Does this address your question? Note that the smoke effect is entirely composed of 2D billboards (moving in 3D space) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jQivfs34Wb0

Comment: @Basic: I need an implementation for Monogame/XNA, not for Unity.